# How to create a R markdown file and append a string variable to the R Markdown document

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am running a shiny application from which I want to create a R markdown file and append a string of characters to the R Markdown document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
rmd_content <- paste0("```Your R markdown string content",string_variable,"```")

rcon <- file("markdown_file.Rmd", "w") # Create Rmarkdown file
cat(rmd_content, file = rcon) # Write your content to Rmarkdown file
close(rcon)
````

After this R code, you should have a file in your current working directory called "markdown_file.Rmd"